# RingCT equivalent for output_histogram

Tags: ringct, available-outputs

Based on the answer and comments to [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/158/determining-the-number-of-available-outputs-by-denomination) about available outputs by denomination, I understand that things will change once RingCT arrives.

Exactly how will the number of outputs change with RingCT? With RingCT can outputs of any denomination be used in a ring signature?

Instead of building a histogram for the number of outputs for a specific denomination how can I calculate the number of possible outputs available for use in a RingCT transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All unlocked rct outputs will be eligible for inclusion in a ring signature. Those outputs will be stored with the placeholder 0 amount, the real amount being unknown except to the recipient (and the sender, though needing extra information kept outside of the blockchain).

Outputs from the block rewards, which will still be in the clear, will also be available as rct inputs, and will be stored as rct outputs. This will make smaller coinbase transactions, even though their amount is known.

To sum up, the number of eligible rct outputs will be the number of unlocked outputs at amount 0 (and there are none before the fork).