# How can one query the blockchain's database?

Tags: blockchain, lmdb, database

I realize that LMDB is very different from your typical SQL database, but is there a query language, or scripting language interface, that can be used to query the blockchain's database?

I am aware of [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/158/determining-the-number-of-available-outputs-by-denomination) on displaying the output histogram via a feature of `monerod`. Although, when trying that my daemon crashed. I would like to do something similar from a script.

Comment: Please file a bug on github about the crash, including what you did exactly, testnet or not, any stack trace and/or error message.

Comment: Well, technically the daemon didn't crash. It just got stuck somehow. I'll follow-up in the other question, as it is kind of off-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent of the mysql or psql commands for lmdb, therefore to make custom queries to the database you must write a program that accesses it directly.

There are some examples at [github.com/moneroexamples](https://github.com/moneroexamples):

- [github.com/moneroexamples/lmdbcpp-monero](https://github.com/moneroexamples/lmdbcpp-monero)
- [github.com/moneroexamples/access-blockchain-in-cpp](https://github.com/moneroexamples/access-blockchain-in-cpp)
- [github.com/moneroexamples/finding-mine-tx-ins-and-outs](https://github.com/moneroexamples/finding-mine-tx-ins-and-outs)
- [github.com/moneroexamples/transactions-export](https://github.com/moneroexamples/transactions-export)

Comment: Thank you for these example project links, they look like good starting points. Could you please make the links clickable (for convenience)?

Answer (score 8):

If you're using python, the py-lmdb module includes a basic CLI. http://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/

Keep in mind that you'll be getting raw data back, not anything in a human-readable format.

Comment: Thank you for this. I also found [LMDB wrappers here](https://symas.com/products/lightning-memory-mapped-database/wrappers/). I suppose these are also good ways to interact with the blockchain database?

Comment: Sure, use whatever language you're comfortable with. Note that all of those are 3rd party projects; I know next to nothing about most of them. I'm familiar with the python module since that author stays in contact with the LMDB project.

Comment: @hyc: I've never been able to get py-lmdb to work with the monero lmdb database. Tried something like https://github.com/Gingeropolous/LMDBExplorer/blob/master/Explorer.py#L4 and get the error "MDB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch". No amount of googling has helped. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to do a custom build of py-lmdb using the version of LMDB in the monero source tree. Monero uses a LMDB 1.0 pre-release, while the rest of the world uses LMDB 0.9.